# How should I go about integrating wagtail-lazyimages with Wagtail's RichTextField?

Tags: django, lazy-loading, wagtail

I'm trying to implement lazy loading for my blog post images, but I'm utilizing RichTextField for my blog posts, so I'm unable to specify each image tag like the [Wagtail-LazyImages](https://libraries.io/pypi/wagtail-lazyimages) documentation suggets I should.

According to the [Wagtail Docs on RichTextField internals](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/rich_text_internals.html), an image may be stored as `<embed embedtype="image" id="10" alt="A pied wagtail" format="left" />` but upon rendering is translated to `<img alt="A pied wagtail" class="richtext-image left" height="294" src="/media/images/pied-wagtail.width-500_ENyKffb.jpg" width="500">` meaning there's not every any explicit tag usage like LazyImages is looking for.

This is more of a conceptual question, as I'm just not sure where in the process to hook into Wagtail's RTF processing.

Could I utilize the register_rich_text_features hook to make a new "feature" for lazy images that will then use the lazyimages class?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by subclassing Format([Changing rich text representation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/images/changing_rich_text_representation.html#changing-rich-text-representation)) in `image_formats.py` file. I overwrote its `image_to_html` method to replace `'src'` attribute with placeholder and add `'data-src'` attribute.

Don't forget to add lazy load library like [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) before closing `</body>` tag.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.html import escape
from wagtail.images.formats import Format, register_image_format
from wagtail.images.shortcuts import get_rendition_or_not_found

class LazyImageFormat(Format):
    def image_to_html(self, image, alt_text, extra_attributes=None):

        if extra_attributes is None:
            extra_attributes = {}
        rendition = get_rendition_or_not_found(image, self.filter_spec)

        #Placeholder scaling based on image height. Needed ONLY if you use this SVG "loading" placeholder.
        svg_width = rendition.width//2
        svg_height = rendition.height//2
        load_scale = rendition.height//100

        #Overwriting 'src' and adding 'data-src' attribute. 'src' - can be any placeholder value
        extra_attributes['src'] = format_html('''data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 {} {}'%3E%3Ccircle cx='{}' cy='{}' fill='none' stroke='%23393939' stroke-width='{}' r='{}' stroke-dasharray='{} {}' transform='rotate(175 50 50)'%3E%3CanimateTransform attributeName='transform' type='rotate' repeatCount='indefinite' dur='2s' values='0 {} {};360 {} {}' keyTimes='0;1'/%3E%3C/circle%3E%3C/svg%3E''',
            rendition.width, rendition.height, svg_width, svg_height, 5*load_scale, 15*load_scale, 70*load_scale, 25*load_scale, svg_width, svg_height, svg_width, svg_height)
        extra_attributes['data-src'] = rendition.url

        extra_attributes['alt'] = escape(alt_text)
        if self.classnames:
            extra_attributes['class'] = "%s" % escape(self.classnames)

        return rendition.img_tag(extra_attributes)

#register our custom LazyImageFormat and add 'lazyload' class 
register_image_format(LazyImageFormat('lazy_fullwidth', 'Centered-1000 lazy', 'richtext-image centered lazyload', 'width-1000'))
register_image_format(LazyImageFormat('lazy_original', 'Original lazy', 'richtext-image centered lazyload', 'original'))
```